# Win7 OpenSSH config: no address associated with name

Tags: windows-7, ssh, openssh

I am using OpenSSH on win7.  My home dir is `C:\Users\JG`, and inside that dir I have the file `C:\Users\JG\.ssh\config`, with these contents:

```
Host <redacted server ip here>
HostName digitalocean_git
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/digitalocean_moocho/id_rsa
```

The id file pointed to by the "IdentityFile" entry works, as I use it just fine via putty, but for this problem I am trying to get command line OpenSSH working.

The crux of the problem is explained by this output:

```
>ssh -v digitalocean_git
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/JG/.ssh/config
ssh: digitalocean_git: no address associated with name
```

Why is no address associated with the name?  How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had "Host" and "HostName" confused.  When I put the IP as "HostName" and the alias as "Host", it worked fine.